DRAM destructive read
As far as I understand, i can describe the DRAM read sequence as follows:

Precharge the bitline (BL) to 0.5VDD
Turn on the access transistor
The BL voltage changes to 0.5VDD ± ε
The voltage level at the storage node is corrupted (neither VDD nor 0V)
The sense amplifier compares the BL voltage with a reference voltage (0.5VDD)
The sense amplifier amplifies the BL voltage to a full logic level (0V or VDD) based on the read data
The BL is now either at 0V or VDD, and the access transistor is still ON
Since the access transistor is ON and the BL is at a full logic level, the storage node is restored

My question is: does the term "destructive read" in DRAM specifically refer to the 4th step in this sequence, where the storage node voltage is corrupted? And if so, is it correct to say that by the end of the read operation, the data is restored to its original state?

It's not "corrupted", it follows the charge-sharing rule. Once you've read the value, you can't read it again as voltage levels have leveled out.

@edmz I think step 6~7 is very similar to a write operation, so the value is recovered immediately after the read, so I think we can read the value until the refresh is needed.

(Do you know the description on en.wikipedia?)
